# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: com.dosideas.cxf.Item is not known to this context

Tags: cxf

I'm quite new with apache cxf, I have developed a web service using this tech.

XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, cxf-2.1.3.jar, geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar, geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar, geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.3.jar, geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar, geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar, jaxb-api-2.1.jar, jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar, neethi-2.0.4.jar, saaj-api-1.3.jar, saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar, wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar, xml-resolver-1.2.jar

This is the interface:

```
@WebService
public interface StoreAdmin
{
    boolean logIn(@WebParam(name="legajo") String legajo
             ,@WebParam(name="lat")   String lat
             ,@WebParam(name="lon")   String lon)                                                           throws StoreException;

    boolean logOut(@WebParam(name="legajo") String legajo)                                                      throws StoreException;


    boolean addItemToSystem(@WebParam(name="isbn") String isbn
                       ,@WebParam(name="descripcion") String descripcion
                       ,@WebParam(name="precio") double precio
                       ,@WebParam(name="numeroTotal") int numeroTotal)                                              throws StoreException;
    @WebResult(name="item")
    com.dosideas.cxf.Item getItem(@WebParam(name="isbn") String isbn)                                               throws StoreException;

    }
```

This is the implementation file:

```
  package com.dosideas.cxf;

  import com.dosideas.cxf.exception.StoreException;
  import com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioEncriptacion;
  import com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioItems;
  import com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioUsuarios;
  import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;
  import javax.jws.WebService;

  /**
  *
  * @author alonso
  */
  @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.dosideas.cxf.StoreAdmin",serviceName="storeAdmin")
  public class StoreAdminImpl implements StoreAdmin{

   //injectd by spring
   private ServicioUsuarios            servicioUsuarios;
   private ServicioEncriptacion        servicioEncriptacion;
   private ServicioItems               servicioItems;

   //constructor...
   StoreAdminImpl(ServicioUsuarios _servicioUsuarios
            , ServicioEncriptacion _servicioEncriptacion
            ,ServicioItems _servicioItems)
   {
    this.servicioUsuarios=_servicioUsuarios;
    this.servicioEncriptacion=_servicioEncriptacion;
    this.servicioItems=_servicioItems;        
}

... 
// there are more methods but I don't put here, not relevant

 public Item getItem(String isbn) throws StoreException {
    return servicioItems.getItem(isbn);
}

public ServicioUsuarios getServicioUsuarios()
{
    return servicioUsuarios;
}
```

}

ServicioItemsImpl.getItem method:

hashMapItems is a concurrentHashMap

```
  public Item getItem(String isbn) throws StoreException
  {
     Logger.getLogger(ServicioItemsImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "ServicioItemsImpl. INIT getItem.");

     Item item = (Item ) ServicioItemsImpl.hashMapItems.get(isbn);
     if (item==null)
     {
        Logger.getLogger(ServicioItemsImpl.class.getName()).log(
            Level.WARNING, "ServicioItemsImpl. METHOD: getItem. ERROR. el item con isbn: {0} no existe en el sistema.", isbn);

        //throw new StoreException("27",isbn,null);
     }
     else
      Logger.getLogger(ServicioItemsImpl.class.getName()).log(
            Level.INFO, "ServicioItemsImpl. END isbn´s Item: {0}",item.getIsbn());

     return item;

}
```

the applicationContext.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />


<!-- Declaramos el bean implementación del Servicio Web. Como vemos, es
     un bean más de Spring, por lo que podemos inyectarle dependencias,
     interceptores, y demás.
-->
<bean id="holaMundoImpl" class="com.dosideas.cxf.HolaMundoImpl"/>

<bean id="servicioUtiles" class="com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioUtilesImpl"/>

<bean id="servicioUsuarios" class="com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioUsuariosImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioUtiles"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioEncriptacion"/>
</bean>

<bean id="servicioEncriptacion" class="com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioEncriptacionImpl"/>

<bean id="servicioItems" class="com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioItemsImpl"/>

<bean id="servicioApuntesContables" class="com.dosideas.cxf.service.ServicioApuntesContablesImpl"/>

<bean id="storeImpl" class="com.dosideas.cxf.StoreImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioUsuarios"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioEncriptacion"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioItems"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioApuntesContables"/>
</bean>

<bean id="storeAdminImpl" class="com.dosideas.cxf.StoreAdminImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioUsuarios"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioEncriptacion"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="servicioItems"/>
</bean>


<!-- Declaramos el endpoint de nuestro servicio web, indicando cual es la
     clase de implementación. En el atributo "implementor" podemos escribir
     el nombre completo de la clase implementación, o referenciar a un
     bean de Spring usando un # seguido del nombre del bean.
-->
<jaxws:endpoint
  id="holaMundo"
  implementor="#holaMundoImpl"
  address="/HolaMundo" />

<jaxws:endpoint
  id="store"
  implementor="#storeImpl"
  address="/StoreImpl" />

<jaxws:endpoint
  id="storeAdmin"
  implementor="#storeAdminImpl"
  address="/StoreAdminImpl" />
```

this is my test junit file:

```
@Test
public void testGetItem()
{
    Logger.getLogger(StoreAdminTest.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "INIT testGetDescriptionItem");

    try
    {
        boolean retorno = instance.addItemToSystem("8717418323691", "Castle Tercera Temporarada DVD",39.95,100);
        assertEquals(true,retorno);

        //broken here
        //org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: com.dosideas.cxf.Item is not known to this context

        Item item = instance.getItem("8717418323691");
        assertEquals(true, item!=null);
        assertEquals("Castle Tercera Temporarada DVD",item.getDescripcion());

    } catch (StoreException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StoreAdminTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Logger.getLogger(StoreAdminTest.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "END testGetDescriptionItem");

}
```

the item pojo class:

```
package com.dosideas.cxf;

/**
*
* @author alonso
*/
public class Item {

private String isbn;
private String descripcion;
private double precio;
private int numeroTotal;

Item(){};
Item(String isbn,String descripcion,double precio,int numeroTotal)
{
    this.isbn=isbn;
    this.descripcion=descripcion;
    this.precio=precio;
    this.numeroTotal=numeroTotal;
};

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public int getNumeroTotal() {
    return numeroTotal;
}

public void setNumeroTotal(int numeroTotal) {
    this.numeroTotal = numeroTotal;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}


public void decrementarNumeroTotal()
{
    if (getNumeroTotal()>0)
        setNumeroTotal(getNumeroTotal() - 1);
    else
        setNumeroTotal(0);
}
```

}

The exception log:

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: com.dosideas.cxf.Item is not known to this context

I don't know what´s going on, and I spent 3 days reading blogs, please help!!

Comment: Your `Item` class is not annotated by JAXB. It looks like your are new to this technology and if so I would suggest you to generate beans from WSDL using `wsimport`, play with this and if you feel confident, modify beans.

Comment: thx for the response dma_k, im quite newbee with cxf but not developing webservices. It looks like cxf doesnt marshall the item pojo, why the frakking hell does not do it? in the meanwhile, i´ll check wsimport

Comment: hi again, i have solved my problem, sorry, the default scope constructor wasnt public, arggg. anyway, thx the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem, sorry, the default scope constructor wasnt public, arggg. anyway, thx the answer